# Why is the expanding card preview text increasing after being opened and closed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I have found this Codepen that I wish to use and it's perfect apart from the fact that once you open and close a card, the preview text reveals more than before it was opened.

https://codepen.io/Beardwig/pen/RZExaj

I think it has something to do with this class however I'm not entirely sure

```
<div class='expd-truncate'>
```

This is the link to the Codepen, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The page is using JavaScript to show and hide the truncated text, as opposed to a [CSS approach](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/). Simply put, the page starts with the text truncated (hard-coded in the HTML), however after showing it and hiding it, it doesn't re-truncate it; it just uses `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

The text is truncated by javascript.
When closing the card, the javascript function that truncates again the text is called too much early:

```
$('.expd-truncate',thisCard).snipper({height: '60px'});
```

should be called at the very end of your code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the class, nor in fact the CSS at all, but rather that after expanding and contracting the card there is too much content inside of the `div.expd-truncate` and the `p` tag within it - prior to the expansion it is a call to the `.snipper` method when the document is ready which truncates that content and appends an ellipsis to keep the content from being too long. I'm referring to this part of the code on line 74 of the CodePen:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.expd-truncate').snipper({height: '60px'});
});
```

The bug is caused by the `.snipper` method being called prior to the alteration of the classes governing the display of the content being snipped when the button to retract/un-expand the card is clicked. Thus, when the card is retracted, the content gets snipped, then the classes are changed and the layout changes accordingly and the content reflows, and now the content is ultimately a different height than it was when it was snipped.

So the solution is to simply call the `.snipper` method after the alteration of the classes (ie line 117 (`$('.expd-truncate',thisCard).snipper({height: '60px'});`) should be below lines 118-121).

See this fork I made of the CodePen above for a working demonstration:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBezWG

Or check out the JS in this working snippet, which is equivalent but with plain HTML and CSS:

```js
(function($){
 "use strict"
 
 $.fn.snipper = function(options) {
  var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.snipper.defaults, options),
   trimText = function($el, height, ellipsis) {
    // Make sure HTML entities only count as one character
    var ellipsisNumChars = ellipsis.replace(/&[^;]+?;/g, '.').length;

    while ($el.outerHeight() > height) {
     if ($el.text().length <= ellipsisNumChars) {
      break;
     }

     $el.html(function(i, text) {
      if (/\s/.test(text)) {
       return text.replace(/\s*(\S)*$/, ellipsis);
      }
      
      // If there is just one really long string without spaces
      // start stripping the last character and concatinating the ellipsis
      return text.replace(new RegEx('.{' + (ellipsisNumChars + 1) + '}$'), ellipsis);
     });
    }
   };

  this.each(function(){
   var $el = $(this),
    fullText = opts.fullText || $el.data('snipper:fullText'),
    height = opts.height,
    ellipsis = opts.ellipsis || '';

   // If height is a function get its return value
   if (typeof(height) === 'function') {
    height = height.apply(this);
   }

   if (!height) {
    return;
   }

   height = parseInt(height, 10);

   if (isNaN(height)) {
    return;
   }

   if (fullText) {
    if (typeof(fullText) === 'function') {
     fullText = fullText.apply(this);
    }

    $el.html(fullText);
   } else {
    $el.data('snipper:fullText', $el.html());
   }

   trimText($el, height, ellipsis);
  });

  return this;
 };
 
 $.fn.snipper.defaults = {
  ellipsis: '&hellip;'
 };
}(jQuery))

//none/grow pulse/grow, bounceIn/grow, BounceInUp/slide, fadeInUp/slide, lightSpeedIn/slide, rotateInUpLeft/fade, rollIn/slide, zoomIn/fade, slideInUp/slide
var speed = 300,
    animClassIn = "pulse",
    animClassOut = "fadeIn",
    expandStyle = "grow";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.expd-truncate').snipper({height: '60px'});
});
//
//Expand
//
$(document).on("click",".wrap-expd-card .expd-card-toggle" , function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).closest(".expd-card"),
      cardLeft = thisCard.offset().left,
      cardTop = thisCard.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.expd-truncate',thisCard).snipper({height: '9999px'});
  thisCard.parent(".wrap-expd-card").addClass("expd-hold");
  thisCard.prependTo("body");
  $("body").addClass("expd-body");
  thisCard.addClass("expd-pre-anim").css({left: cardLeft, top: cardTop});
  thisCard.removeClass("out-anim "+animClassOut);
  thisCard.css('opacity');
  if(expandStyle == "grow") {
    thisCard.removeClass("expd-pre-anim").addClass("expd-active").css({left: 0, top: 0, transition: "all "+speed+"ms ease", opacity: 1});
    thisCard.addClass(animClassIn);
  } else if (expandStyle == "slide") {
    thisCard.animate({
      top: '100%'
    }, 100, function () {
      thisCard.removeClass("expd-pre-anim").addClass("expd-active");
    }).promise().done(function () {
      thisCard.addClass(animClassIn);
    }); 
  } else if (expandStyle == "fade") {
    thisCard.removeClass("expd-pre-anim").addClass("expd-active").css({left: 0, top: 0,opacity: 1, transition: "opacity "+speed+"ms"});
    thisCard.addClass(animClassIn);
  }
});
//
//Retract
//
$(document).on("click",".expd-body .expd-card-toggle", function() {
  var thisCard = $(this).closest(".expd-card"),
      cardLeft = $(".expd-hold").offset().left,
      cardTop = $(".expd-hold").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  thisCard.removeClass("expd-active "+animClassIn).addClass("expd-pre-anim").css({left: cardLeft, top: cardTop, opacity: 0});
  thisCard.animate({scrollTop:0},speed);
  //setTimeout(function(){ 
  thisCard.removeClass("expd-pre-anim").css({left: 0, top: 0, opacity: 1}); 
  thisCard.appendTo(".wrap-expd-card.expd-hold").addClass(animClassOut);
  $(".wrap-expd-card").removeClass("expd-hold");
  $("body").removeClass("expd-body");
  $('.expd-truncate',thisCard).snipper({height: '60px'});
  //}, 0);//
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
.expd-card,
.expd-card * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap-expd-card {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px;
}
.expd-card.fadeIn {
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-delay: 0ms;
}
.expd-card {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #7c7c7c;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-delay: 200ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap .expd-card-img {
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background: #bbb;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap .expd-card-content {
  margin: 18px 16px;
  position: relative;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap .expd-card-content .expd-card-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #f00;
  right: 16px;
  top: -36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap .expd-card-content .expd-heading h2 {
  color: #383838;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap .expd-card-content .expd-heading strong {
  color: #585858;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.expd-card .expd-card-body-wrap .expd-card-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
.expd-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.expd-card.expd-pre-anim {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}
.expd-card.expd-active {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <title>fiddle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body class="">
  <div class="wrap-expd-card">
   <div class="expd-card animated fadeIn" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; transition: all 300ms ease 0s; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="expd-card-body-wrap">
     <div class="expd-card-img">
     </div>
     <div class="expd-card-content">
      <div class="expd-card-toggle">
      </div>
      <div class="expd-heading">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
       <strong>Subtitle</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="expd-truncate">
       <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.</p>
       <p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
       <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.</p>
       <p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-expd-card">
   <div class="expd-card animated">
    <div class="expd-card-body-wrap">
     <div class="expd-card-img">
     </div>
     <div class="expd-card-content">
      <div class="expd-card-toggle">
      </div>
      <div class="expd-heading">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
       <strong>Subtitle</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="expd-truncate">
       <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.</p>
       <p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
       <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.</p>
       <p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-expd-card">
   <div class="expd-card animated">
    <div class="expd-card-body-wrap">
     <div class="expd-card-img">
     </div>
     <div class="expd-card-content">
      <div class="expd-card-toggle">
      </div>
      <div class="expd-heading">
       <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
       <strong>Subtitle</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="expd-truncate">
       <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.</p>
       <p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
       <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.</p>
       <p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```